# Using 'the' with 'my'

Tags: sentence-construction

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this grammar? Or what should be removed or added to make the grammar right in this sentence?

> The beat suits my mood today.

I changed the '**fits** my mood today' to '**suits** my mood today' after seeing [this article](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/fit-or-suit).

*Edit: This is a textbook exercise. A picture of a woman listening to music. And I came up with this sentence.*

Comment: Do you mean the beat heard in a song or music? What makes you think it is not right?

Comment: Yes. It is a textbook exercise with the picture of a woman listening to music. And I came up with this sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The beat suits my mood.
- The beat fits my mood.
- The beat pumps up my mood.
- The beat lightens my mood.

Both are fine, and I am sure there are many, many more.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand the vada part. :) [ha ha].